# Wordpress database problem wp_posts, primary key

Tags: plugins, database, mysql

Repende my website in wordpress did not let me work properly, did not let me publish an article and showed me a problem in the editor show the message: "You are editing the page that shows your latest posts."

Searching on the Internet seems to be a problem of the database, when entering the wp_post phpmyadmin table I get this message "The current selection does not contain a single column. The grid edition and the copy, delete and edit links do not are available "I can not modify the data in the table, I also see that the structure is different from any other database in wordpress, the wp_posts table for example the ID has no auto increment and has no primary key when it should have it. I try to assign it but I get this error:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` ADD PRIMARY KEY (` ID`);

MySQL said: Documentation

# 1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for the key 'PRIMARY'
```

[image]

Any way to solve this problem? I have already updated the wordpress, used plugin to "repair" database but nothing worked for me

I appreciate your help

Comment: look in the table how many post you have where ID is 0.

Comment: hello, already check and none, the ID start from 4